# Update your apps to be 64-bit

Tags: android, 64-bit

Google Play has been sending email to me yesterday entitled "Action required: Update your apps to be 64-bit compliant by August 1, 2019" for two games

I don't know how to make my games support 64-bit by android studio 
I hope someone explains how

edit: my games build by buildbox 2D

Comment: Without knowing how your games were built and with what libraries (Unity, cocos-2d, etc.) you'll need to follow the Android documentation in [Ensure that your app supports 64-bit devices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

Comment: Haven't used BB in years but I remember they had a very active official forum, is there no FAQ on this issue? EDIT: There is apparently an update coming soon, maybe it would be a good idea to ask the developers for the definitive answer https://www.buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/bb2-warning-this-release-is-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement.16878/

Comment: Unfortunately, the two games build by BB but I have an only android studio code source

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your app's build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.app'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
   appId "com.google.example.64bit"
   minSdkVersion 15
   targetSdkVersion 28
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

// ...

For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.

For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for 64-bit.

For detail https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit